# Male Micro usb to male XLR cable?

Tags: cable, xlr

I have a Blue Yeti microphone which has a female micro USB port which I need to connect to a mixer which has a female XLR port.  I have been looking for a cable which is male micro usb on one end and make XLR on the other end, but can only find male micro usb to female XLR cables .  Is there such a thing as male micro usb to male xlr or will I have to use a cable with female XLR on the end plus a gender switch adapter?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect a USB microphone to an XLR port. The signal from the USB connector is simply a data-stream whereas the XLR port requires an analogue signal input. What you are proposing cannot be achieved. You have the wrong type of microphone. Any attempt to connect one to the other may damage the microphone. Do not attempt this.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the reply.  If you don’t mind I have a follow up question.  The output from my mixer is also XLR.  Can I use an XLR to USB cable to take the output signal into my computer or will that just give me the reverse problem ( in which case I guess I just got the wrong kind of mixer).

Comment: Exactly the same problem. The output from your mixer is analogue. USB is a device specific digital data stream. It's like connecting chalk to cheese. Some mixers will have a USB connection designed to connect directly to computers - evidently not this one. The mic you have is designed to connect directly to a computer and nowhere else. So you have the wrong mic to use with a mixer and the wrong mixer to use with a computer. If you want to use a mixer with a computer, best get a standard analogue mic and a mixer with a USB connection.

Comment: Mark, thanks again.  Some other internet searches seem to confirm that I can’t use it to the USB input, but seem to say I could use the 3.5mm microphone input on the PC. That seems to make sense to me as a fallback until getting a different t mixer.

Comment: You are likely to run into issues with the output levels here. XLR main outputs are generally what is known as 'line' level, which is a significantly higher level than 'consumer mic' level, which is what the 3.5mm mic input on the PC will be expecting. If you can, find a 'line' input on the PC, that should work. If you can't, you will need to find some way of attenuating the signal before connecting it to the PC mic input.

Comment: The mixer also has left and right 1/4 inch outputs so I can use a y 1/4” to single 3.5mm for now